# Webdriverio. JS. Mocha. When trying to import page objects - error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm writing automation tests and trying to use the page object pattern, that's why I need to import page objects into the test files.
According to Webdriverio docs, in order to enable import, I need to install Babel. I did install it, however it didn't fix the problem. I used the command from the Webdriverio docs: npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/register
The Webdriverio doc also says that the following changes need to be added to the wdio.conf.js file:

```
        ui: 'bdd',
        require: ['@babel/register', './test/helpers/common.js'],
```

I tried to do that, but I don't seem to have ./test/helpers/common.js directory of common.js file. What should this directory refer to? If I need to create the common.js file what should it contain?
Node version: 12.13.0
Webdriverio: 6.1.5
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try removing that file? It should still work.

Comment: Yes, I tried removing the './test/helpers/common.js' directory and leaving require: ['@babel/register'] only, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have a sample repo on github or something which I can look at?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is the link to the repository with my config file and a sample test: 
https://github.com/yuliiadratch/Webdriverio

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing the config file (babel.config.js) for babeljs. You should have it in the root.

Below is what you should have inside it as per official docs [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/babel.html).

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {
            targets: {
                node: 12 //version should be based on which version you need.
            }
        }]
    ]
}
```

You can read more about this file [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files).

I have created a working example [here](https://github.com/spnraju/demo-webdriverio-mochajs) for your reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem

Comment: Did you check the project I have created?

Comment: There was a problem with my setup. Everything works now, thank you so much for your patience, time and help :)

Comment: So what was the issue with your setup?

Comment: Apparently, I overlooked a step when setting the project up, because my wdio.config.js file wasn't generated automatically the first time. When I tried to run the test I got the message that there was no config file and was offered to create it by selecting the necessary options, which apparently didn't go well for me. Anyways, I reinstalled webdriverio, this time correctly and now it works perfectly. I feel sorry for not thinking of reinstalling it earlier. Sorry for taking up your time and thank you very much for your patience and all your help, I really appreciate it :)